# Angular Reactive Form not populating with new array

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form in my angular application, and I'm trying to submit a form that includes an array.

In my ngOnInit() I populate the form as follows:

```
  this.userForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [result.id, Validators.required],
    firstName: [result.firstName, Validators.required],
    lastName: [result.lastName, Validators.required],
    roles: this.fb.array([])
  });
```

When submitting the form, I'm trying to add the contents on a string array into my form.

I'm adding my string array to the form like this:

```
this.userForm.controls.roles = this.roles.filter(x=>x.selected == true).map(x=>x.name)
```

This seems to work:

```
console.log(this.userForm.controls.roles)
```

gives me:

```
["Administrator", "Manager"]
```

However when I check the contents of my userForm (which is what I'm submitting), roles is blank:

```
console.log(this.userForm.value)

firstName: "John"
id: "4efba5d3-1875-4496-aeca-6f372924a700"
lastName: "Smith"
roles: []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are assigning an array or strings (["Administrator", "Manager"]) to an array of AbstractControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't

```
this.userForm.controls.roles = this.roles.filter(x=>x.selected == true).map(x=>x.name)
```

instead, do

```
this.userForm.patchValue(
   { roles: this.roles.filter(x=>x.selected == true).map(x=>x.name) }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use `this.userForm.patchValue({roles: this.roles.filter(x=>x.selected == true).map(x=>x.name)})` instead of changing the controls of the form.